# How to disable <user-folder> and `Libraries` item in Windows 7 sidebar?

Tags: windows-7, sidebar

Im annoyed by these two items in the sidebar. I never use them.
If you know how to get rid of them, please share.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Good question. I am also annoyed by the Favorites and would like to only leave Computer and Network there, so if anyone can answer inclusively of disabling those, that would be awesome!

Comment: Favorites are the way to go.  I guess some people still prefer multiple click vs doing things the easy way. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the scripts [from here](http://media.askvg.com/downloads/2009/09/Disable%20Libraries%20in%20Windows%207.zip). Its simple registry scripts, that either disable Libraries in Windows 7, or only remove Libraries icon from Windows 7 Explorer, or restore to default settings.

Tested on my machine and it works fine.

Found on [askvg.com](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-libraries-feature-in-windows-7/)

Comment: How about removing `User` folder

Comment: @NamGiVU: You can try [this tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/48123-user-folder-add-remove-navigation-pane.html)

Comment: I tried your scripts in the answer, it removes both `Library` and `User`. Cheers.